# What kinds of inner product or norm or metric or topology are defined on $C_0(X)$ and on $C_c(X)$ for Riesz representation theorems?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space. What kinds of inner product or norm or metric or topology are defined on $C_0(X)$ and on $C_c(X)$ for [their Riesz representation theorems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem) respectively, so that we can talk about  positive linear functionals on $C_c(X)$ and continuous linear functionals on $C_0(X)$?

Wikipedia says for [the relations between the two representation theorems for $C_c(X)$ and $C_0(X)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem#The_representation_theorem_for_the_dual_of_C0.28X.29)

> Remark. One might expect that by the Hahn-Banach theorem for bounded
>   linear functionals, every bounded linear functional on $C_c(X)$ extends
>   in exactly one way to a bounded linear functional on $C_0(X)$, the latter
>   being the closure of $C_c(X)$ in the supremum norm, and that for this
>   reason the first statement implies the second. However the first
>   result is for positive linear functionals, not bounded linear
>   functionals, so the two facts are not equivalent.
>
> In fact, a bounded linear functional on $C_c(X)$ need not remain so if
>   **the locally convex topology** on $C_c(X)$ is replaced by **the supremum norm**,
>   the norm of $C_0(X)$. An example is the Lebesgue measure on R, which is
>   bounded $C_c(X)$ but unbounded on $C_0(X)$. This fact can also be seen by
>   observing that the total variation of the Lebesgue measure is
>   infinite.

So is the topology on $C_0(X)$ the supremum norm and its topology, and the topology on $C_c(X)$ the locally convex topology? How is the latter topology defined?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 1):

Unless otherwise stated, the norm on (subspaces of) $BC(X\to \mathbb K)$, the set of bounded continuous $\mathbb K$-valued functions on a Hausdorff space $X$, is always the uniform norm.

At least I can't see any reason why it should default to anything else…

Comment: Thanks! In http://math.stackexchange.com/a/36712/1281, "But positivity does not imply continuity. The Lebesgue integral is positive but discontinuous on $C_c(\mathbb R)$. – scineram", "@scineram: I was allowing myself to be a bit sloppy in my answer. Sorry about the confusion. It depends of course on what topology you put on $C_c(\mathbb R)$ and I decided to sweep that under the rug. – t.b."

Comment: Hi Kahen, I just updated my post to add more of my confusion.